# Jmeter slave report filter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

1. Is there a way we can filter the response times, erros in apex report of jmeter group by slaves?
2. How can we change the ms to sec in apdex report?

Answer (score 0):

1. For the existing results it's not possible, going forward you can consider adding [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions to sampler labels, this way you will get slave hostname/ip address as [sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)/[transaction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) prefix or postfix
2. There is no simple "switch", you will have to go through the [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.4/bin/report-template) and divide the metrics by 1000 using JavaScript function where required